# How to know if a process is user or root in bash, linux

Tags: linux, bash

I need to know if a process is from the user or not.
I'm using this code:

```
#c is the PID
Aid=$(cat /proc/$c/status | grep -e ^Uid) 
Uid="Uid:   0   0   0   0"
if [ "$Aid" != "$Uid" ]; then
    echo "is from user"
fi
```

But I'm not very comfortable with the "tabs" in the string, i think that maybe can cause some unexpected behavior.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Wait I think I misunderstood the question. Are you trying to get the UID of a certain PID, and not your script?

Comment: yes, from a arbitrary process.

Comment: Can you use the `stat` syscall on anything in `/proc/<pid>`? But tab delimited string is reasonable to match against, because if it's in `/proc` you're not going to get tripped up by user input.

Comment: @Sobrique so, this is a "good" way to do it?

Comment: To an extent, it depends _why_ you're trying to do it. I would probably use `ps` to get a bit more platform independence. (e.g. as in the solution below_)

Comment: Is for a college assignment, so i can't use ps. Another question, the user id is always 1000? @Sobrique

Comment: Nope. Not at all. Only uid 0 has any special significance.  Any other number can be user.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! @Sobrique

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the UID of a certain pid without parsing using `ps -o uid= -p $pidhere`:

```
mypid=1
if uid=$(ps -o uid= -p "$mypid")
then
  if [[ $uid -eq 0 ]]
  then
    echo "The process runs as root"
  else
    echo "The process runs as something else"
  fi
else
  echo "The process doesn't exist"
fi
```

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants to check if some arbitrary process (my assumption based on the use of a variable `$c` instead of say `self`).

Comment: yes, i want to check if some arbitrary process is user or root

Comment: Similar principle applies though - actual uid doesn't really matter much, compared to capabilities. (Or at least, shouldn't - most people are lazy enough that there's `root` and "everyone else".)

Comment: the process from the user are always UID = 1000?

Comment: @exsnake No, definitely not.